# Quotes error when passing php string value to javascript onClick

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to passing variable from php to Javascript. But it can only passing integer type. When I pass value that is not integer, the variable value is undefined.

```
<?php
$sqlCall="SELECT * FROM table";
$resCall=mysqli_query($con, $sqlCall);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resCall)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row[id]."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row[name]."</td>";
  echo "<a onclick='edit(".$row['id'].",'".$row['name']."')'>Edit</a>"
?>
```

and here is my JavaScript:

```
<script>
function edit(id, name){
  document.getElementById('edit_id').value = id;
  document.getElementById('edit_name').value = name;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem comes from the single quotes `'` use `&quot;` instead like :

```
"<a onclick='edit(".$row['id'].",&quot;".$row['name']."&quot;)'>Edit</a>"
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still error. It says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token